# make two column layout having the same height

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I used jquery and css to create a 2 column layout. One column is with div main-content, the other is sidebar.

The jquery code is

```
var divone = jQuery(".main-content").height();
var divtwo = jQuery(".sidebar").height();
var mainheight = $(window).height() - $('header').height() - $('footer').height();
jQuery(".main-content").height(mainheight);
jQuery(".sidebar").height(mainheight);
```

The demo is at [demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/CenND/6/)

My question is that it only works well in firefox and chrome. It is messed up in IE 10.

I hope that it works in all major browsers. Thanks for help.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: you could use display:table or display:flex for this, why the use of jQuery ? height ?

Comment: I am not familiar with display:table. And I have no reason to reject jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i made an edit to [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CenND/15/)

```
var t_height =$('html').height();
var h_height =$('.header').height();
var f_height =$('footer').height();
alert(t_height)
alert(h_height)
alert(f_height)
var div_h = t_height-h_height-f_height;
var divone = jQuery(".main-content").css('height',div_h);
var divtwo = jQuery(".sidebar").css('height',div_h);
```

but suddenky i realized that your example also worked for me in IE10

made some changes to `html`, but they are not nessesary

Comment: Are you sure? If you look at the side bar, link1 and link2 are still under the footer.

Comment: [link1](http://jsfiddle.net/CenND/17/)  and [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/CenND/6/)   ,  both giving me the same look in chrome and ie10 and i can see link1 and link2, with no problem

Comment: I didn't get it for the link at all in my IE 10. Please double check it. The problem is not seeing it or not, it is the layout of sidebar. There are two  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>. They are under the footer.

Comment: remove `position:absolute;` for footer or recalculate it's top with scrip